# add existing entity framework to new asp.net app

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have an entity framework model that I created in one app, and I'd like to import(?) it into a new asp.net app.  How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a, for exemple, a Class Libary project for to make your EF model you can to add this project to another with "Project Reference"

Answer (score 1):

I like to keep my EF models in their own Class Library projects.  Then you can just open the existing project in any new solution in which you want the model to be included.